# Call two web Rest web api one by one in angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have two web api to sync data from local to server. my Data is in master / child form. My need is to once master data is synced then child data to be sent for syncing. I am very new in  angular js. Kindly help me.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 3):

First do the first request, and on the callback do the second:

```
$http.get("firstRequestUrl").then(function(data) {
    // success
    $http.get("secondRequestUrl?myVar=" + data.myVar).then(function(secondData) {
        // second request success
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need a way by which second api should be called if first api is success or rejected.

Comment: This answer is fine - per $http docs `success` and `error` are deprecated, so adding the second GET in the first GETs `.then()` callback ensures it fires only after the first is successful.

DOCS: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http